# Display gallery using a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightgallery to display my images. All is ok but I want to show the gallery in fullscreen mode using a button as like as when I click on image.

This is my code:

```
<LightGallery
      mode="lg-fade"
      index={fullScreenIndex} // selected image index. Managed by state
      appendSubHtmlTo=".lg-item"
      plugins={[lgZoom, lgThumbnail]}
    >
    {
      gallery.map((image: string, index: number) => {
        return (
        <a ref={lightGalleryRef} key={index} className="gallery-item" data-src={image} data-sub-html="-">
          <img src={image} alt="image" />
        </a>
        )
      })
    }
  </LightGallery>

<button onClick={() => openGallery()}></button
```

This is the example that I use in my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/lightgallery-react?file=index.tsx

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself that issue and I put here my solution

in img tag I declared a ref

```js
const lightGalleryImgRefs = useRef<any>([])
```

and I add it like this

```html
<img ref={(element) => { lightGalleryImgRefs.current[index] = element }} src={image} alt="image" />
```

in the button onClick handler I triggered the click like this

```js
lightGalleryRef.current[index]?.click()
```

This is the function triggered in fullscreen mode

```js
const renderFullscreenButton = (onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>, isFullscreen: boolean) => {
    return (
      <FullScreenButton onClick={() => fullScreenHandler(lightGalleryImgRefs, refImgRef?.current?.getCurrentIndex())}>ZOOM</FullScreenButton>
    )
  }
```